# What is the best way to lock down Unity for guest accounts?

Tags: 11.04, unity, guest-session

I have made a Guest user account, where Google Chrome launches at startup. But users are still able to browse all applications from the Unity Launcher.

How can I restrict access to all programs. I want to do this in Unity only (to prove to myself if this is even possible), and only let users see Chrome and LibreOffice.

Currently, they can see all programs and even system settings from the top-right power button.

Comment: Power users will likely still be able to find ways around this lockdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part One**

I think you can solve this doing:

1) Install Compiz Settings Manager from the software center  or by [clicking here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

2) Launch it from System -> Preferences

3) Uncheck Unity like in this picture:

[image]

4) Logout and log back in.

**Part Two**
*Others questions*

1) To disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_run_dialog ''
```

2) To disable the shortcut to open the terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/run_command_terminal ''
```

3)  To add shortcuts to the desktop:

- Right click on Desktop > Create Launcher

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I guess I can place just the Chrome and LibreOffice shortcuts on the desktop. Hopefully my guests won't know how to use Alt + F2 or the terminal!

However, this raises another question. Is there any easy way in Unity to add shortcuts to the desktop? In Gnome you can right click a menu item and add to desktop. Can't seem to find an alternative in Unity?

Comment: Please ask that as a seperate question to benefit the entire community..

Comment: Thanks, asked: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35788/is-there-any-easy-way-in-unity-to-add-shortcuts-to-the-desktop