# Is there any easy way in Unity to add shortcuts to the desktop?

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcuts

In Gnome you can right click a menu item and add to desktop. Can't seem to find a just-as-simple alternative in Unity? Anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

The only way thus far is to create a launcher on the desktop.

**Example for Google Chrome**

1 - Right click on desktop and select **Create Launcher**

2 - Give the application a name Google Chrome

3 - Enter the application command google-chrome

Now the icon for Google Chrome Appears on your desktop.

There's possibly an even easier way of doing this, but I'm unsure at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

At the login page enter classic view and add icons to the desktop as required. When you next revert to unity view they will all be on the desktop.

Comment: This is what I've had to do. Making a launcher manually takes long. This is also long. Until Unity offers more customisability I'm sticking with Gnome 2. But thanks.